# Regression model with non-constant variance

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, count-data

I have a dataset to analysis and the following information is known:
$y_i \sim N(\mu_i, \theta(\mu_i)^2)$
The link function is => $ln(\mu_i) = (\beta)^T X$

$y_i$s are count data. The model parameter is beta and theta.
I need to find an estimation method and fit a model.

I have looked at the over-dispersion model and negative binomial models. But they don't seem quite right ...
Can anybody point me to the right direction ...? :)

Update: After some more research - I am looking for if there is any R-package will model data with the above properties?

Comment: If the $y_{i}$'s are count data then why have you written there that they follow a normal distribution?

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit strange to me as well. The goal is to come up with a model to fit the data with the above property and compare that model with a negative binomial model.

Comment: Just checking - are you assuming the variance is proportional to the mean?

Comment: The explicite assumption is the observations has constant coefficient of variation - I guess implies that the variance is proportional to the mean.

Comment: Constant CV means that the *standard deviation* is proportional to the mean, not the variance.

Comment: Look into a Poisson generalized linear model with log link, Shelly: this is appropriate for count data and for largish $\mu_i$ the distribution will be approximately Normal with variance proportional to the mean.

Comment: The assumption of a constant coefficient of variation is fulfilled if you assume a log-normal distribution with the same $\sigma^2$ in each group.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially answered in comments:

> Look into a Poisson generalized linear model with log link, Shelly: this is appropriate for count data and for largish $_$ the distribution will be approximately Normal with variance proportional to the mean.

– whuber